# jQuery - switching text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, I have:

```
function switch()
{
    if(document.getElementById('mydivid').innerHTML == "Show +")
        document.getElementById('mydivid').innerHTML = "Show -";
    else
        if(document.getElementById('mydivid').innerHTML == "Show -")
            document.getElementById('mydivid').innerHTML = "Show +";
}
```

but I am looking to do this with jQuery. I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mydivid").click(function() {
            // if #mydivid is "Show +" do: $("#mydivid").html("Show -");
            // else if #mydiv is "Show -" do: $("#mydivid").html("Show +");
        });
    });
```

How can I use these `if`s? Or can I use toggler with only one div element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mydivid").click(function() {
            if ($(this).text() === "Show +")
               $(this).text("Show -");
            else
               $(this).text("Show +");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.text()` function to get the div contents as text. Try below code.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/AykeH/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydivid").click(function() {
         if ($(this).text() == 'Show +') {
            $(this).text('Show -');
         } else if ($(this).text() == "Show -") {
            $(this).text('Show +');
         }
    });
});
```

**PS:** Wrap the `.text` inside `$.trim()` if you div has `white space/newline`.

Comment: You don't really need the `else if`; just an `else` is fine, but I suppose it's good to have the explicit behaviour in case the element's text is modified by another bit of JS. +1 for using curly braces around your `if()`s too.

Comment: @JamWaffles True, but the OP original code has it so I add the else if instead of else.

Comment: That's true - I didn't read the OP well enough. I'm not saying it's a bad thing to be explicit in this case, but the option is always there to remove the second `if()` and just have an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydivid").click(function() {
        var that = $(this);

        if(that.text() == 'Show +') that.text('Show -');
        else that.text('Show +');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it by existing text only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydivid").click(function() {
        $(this).text(function(i, old){
            return "Show "+ ( /\+/.test( old) ) ? '-': '+';
        })
    });
});
```

I assume this is for toggling an element in which case toggling a class would be a better solution, but it isn't clear what the full code will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/75uqe/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydivid").click(function() {
        $(this).text(function(i,text) {
            return text === 'Show +' ? 'Show -' : 'Show +';
        });            
    });
});
```